# jQuery selection of element based on class; but only selecting top most parents

Tags: jquery

I am in a situation where I have HTML which is not fixed and it is dynamic. Each time there will be different HTML, but I know there will be occurrences of the class `ui-selected`.

I want to select the element which has class `ui-selected`, but only the top most parents.

Like in the HTML below I should have the `p` tag and the `h3` tag. How can I do this?

```
<p class="ui-selected"><span id='fracs' class="ui-selected">Air pollution is contamination of the indoor or outdoor environment by any chemical, <b class="ui-selected">physical or <span class="ui-selected"> biological </span>agent</b> <i class="ui-selected">that modifies the natural</i> characteristics of the atmosphere. Household combustion devices, motor vehicles, industrial facilities and forest fires are common sources of air pollution. Pollutants of major public health concern include particulate matter, carbon monoxide, ozone, nitrogen dioxide and sulfur dioxide. Outdoor and indoor air pollution cause respiratory and other diseases, which can be fatal.</span></p>
<h3 class="section_head1  ui-selected" >Key facts</h3>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dtQ5E/

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: I want to select only top parent like first p and then h3 element not the children of p tag having same class

Comment: why wouldnt `$('p.ui-selected, h3.ui-selected')` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following selects all `.ui-selected` elements, then [`filter()`s](http://api.jquery.com/filter) them, to only give you those which are "top level" (i.e. don't have any ancestors which are `.ui-selected`.)

<sup>... I think that's what you wanted, at least.</sup>

```
$('.ui-selected').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).parents('.ui-selected').length;
});
```

`filter()` returns a jQuery object, so you can perform your normal operations on it.

```
$('.ui-selected').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).parents('.ui-selected').length;
}).on('click', function () {
    alert("Hi, I'm a top-most .ui-selected, and you just clicked me!");
});
```

Comment: but i need a jquery object in return as for performing next operation.Please?

Comment: @developerCK: It will be a jQuery object.

Comment: it is returning empty array as i run in chrome console on given html

Comment: great solution, but why wouldnt `$('p.ui-selected, h3.ui-selected')` work?

Comment: `closest()` include element itself, it should be `.parents()` instead

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks. I'd have been tearing my hair out on that for hours ;).

Comment: Thanks! @Matt , closet was not working but parent did.

Comment: @Alex: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428485/jquery-selection-of-element-based-on-class-but-only-selecting-top-most-parents/23428553?noredirect=1#comment35905215_23428553. I assumed because the HTML is dynamic, there is no guarantee it will be a `p` or `h3` next time, or they'll be root elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the body tag and select direct children:

```
$("body > .ui-selected")
```

Comment: I don't need all the children just the top most children!

Comment: That is the topmost children, in your example at least

Comment: that's why i wrote html is very dynamic.

Comment: @RGraham: I *think* the problem is that the top-most children which are `.ui-selected` might not be *the* top children.

Comment: @Matt That makes sense. It's not very clear from the question.